# how to add button onclick from a create tabcontent

Tags: android

I am trying to make a tabbed app using **tabhost.** so the problem is that  ** onclick ** added to a button i.e inflated through a layout in the **tabcontent** using **createtab content method** ,is not working.App crashes when the button is clicked. plz take look at the code i have used.
This only the method i have create to add tab and content of the tab dynamically

```
public void addtab(View v)
{
    tabno++;
    tabname = String.valueOf(tabno);
    tabnum++;
    TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    //Lets add the first Tab
    TabHost.TabSpec Spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab");
    // Spec.setContent(R.id.layoutone);
    Spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            final LinearLayout layoutone = new LinearLayout(browser.this);
            layoutone.setId(R.id.layoutone);
            layoutone.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            View adrressvar =getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.xcc,layoutone,false);
            search2=(Button) adrressvar.findViewById(R.id.search2);
            urltwo=(EditText)  adrressvar.findViewById(R.id.urlbar2);

            search2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    wb.loadUrl(keyword+urltwo.getText().toString());
                }
            });

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams wbprm= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            wb= new WebView(browser.this);
            wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            wb.loadUrl(ty);

            wb.setId(R.id.wbdy);

            layoutone.addView(adrressvar);
            layoutone.addView(wb,wbprm);
            return layoutone;
        }
    });

    Spec.setIndicator("TAB" + tabname);
    mTabHost.addTab(Spec);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(tabnum);
}
```

logcat  error
04-04 14:21:23.722 14715-14715/com.example.lenovo1.tabhostbrowser E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.lenovo1.tabhostbrowser, PID: 14715
                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4417)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4258)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4198)
                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4171)
                                                                                        at com.example.lenovo1.tabhostbrowser.browser$1$1.onClick(browser.java:114)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: So the app crashes without any error in LogCat? Please post Error code also in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created an instance of your `WebView` prior to using method `loadUrl` on button click? Like `new WebView();`

If yes - make sure also that what you are passing into `loadUrl` is not `null`.

I cannot give more information at this time, because you have not provided any error message that happens when your App crashes.

Comment: Mind trying it out if that will work? Prior using any wv methods.